# How can I upload a video to Firebase using angularfire2?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am building a web app using Angular2 and Firebase, and am using angularfire2 for authentication and database interactions. It seems like angularfire2 [does not have support for the Firebase storage API yet](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/213). 
What is the alternative until then? 
Can I access the Firebase object and follow the [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) in the Firebase documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes...

just use the firebase object and follow the directions on website

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I used `declare var firebase:any;` after the import statements to get access to the firebase object as described in https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/326

Answer (score 2):

I use different approach by

1. create static html+js for the sake of upload only
2. make angular2 make a popup of upload page then when it complete upload close it self + change state of localStorage
3. use ngZone + window.addEventListener("storage") to be able to call back after uploading is done

here is other ppl example to use ngZone
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Nice suggestion. Do you have a gist for how you're doing this?